# RewriteRule for special characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have checked through the threads all day and cant make this work.

When i input **"ö"** in my search box the the url result become **"%25C3%25B6"**

So I search for "Örebro" and the search gives  "%25C3%25B6rebro"

I try fix this with htaccess.

This is what I tried and many other options but nothing works.

```
RewriteRule ^%25C3%25B6(.*) ö$1 [L,R=301]
```

**This is how my url looks like:**
www.domain.com/search/%25C3%25B6rebro

**I need it like this**
www.domain.com/search/örebro

I can make it work when is a simple word but it do not work when it contain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need a rule that allows special characters.  Have you tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/?$ search=$1 [NC,L]
```